# Get all items of a list in listbox

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I hope you can help me with this problem.

I can't get my Beers in the listbox. When i try to do this i get this in my listbox: 
[image]

I dont know how i get this object in a listbox

I have tried it with the following code:
Here i ask the database to select all characteristics from the beertable.

```
public List <Beer> ReadBeers()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM beer";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    List<Beer> beerList = new List <Beer>();

    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string name = reader.GetString(1);
            string brand = reader.GetString(2);
            int dato = reader.GetInt32(3);
            int beerType = reader.GetInt32(4);
            Beer myBeer = new Beer(name, brand, dato, beerType);
            beerList.Add(myBeer);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    return beerList;
}
```

> This is the listbox of the form i want to fill with correct information!

```
private void fillListbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    beerlistBox.Items.Clear();
    dbbeer.DatabaseConnect();
    List<Beer> beerList = dbbeer.ReadBeers();
    foreach (Beer beer in beerList)
    {
        beerlistBox.Items.Add(beer);
    }
    dbbeer.DatabaseDisconnect();
}
```

The Class Beer:

```
class Beer
{
    private Database databaseconnection = new Database(); 

    public enum Biersoort
    {
        Alcoholarm,
        Alcoholvrij,
        Ale,
        Alt,
        Amber,
        Blond,
        Bock,
        Champagnebier,
        Cider,
        Dortmunder,
        Dubbel,
        Dunkel_weizen,
        Eisbock,
        Faro,
        Fruit,
        Gerstebier,
        Gerstewijn,
        Geuze,
        Gose,
        Gruit,
        Herfstbok,
        Honingbier,
        Kellerbier,
        Koffiebier,
        Kriek,
        Lager,
        Lambiek,
        Lentebier,
        Lentebok,
        Light,
        Mexicaans,
        Oud_bruin,
        Pale_Ale,
        Pils,
        Porter,
        Quadrupel_bier,
        Radler,
        Rosé,
        Saison,
        Schwarzbier,
        Stout,
        Tequila_bier,
        Tripel_bier,
        Vruchtenbock,
        Weizen,
        Whiskeybier,
        Winterbier,
        Wit
    };


    private string name;
    private string brand;
    private int dato;
    private int beertype;

    public Beer(string pName, string pBrand, int pDato, int pBeertype)
    {
        name = pName;
        brand = pBrand;
        dato = pDato;
        beertype = pBeertype;
    }

    public void insertDatabase()
    {
        databaseconnection.DatabaseInsert("INSERT INTO beer(name, brand, dato, beertype) VALUES('" + name + "' , '" + brand + "' ,'" + dato + "' , '" + beertype + "' )");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: when you debug the application stepping through the while loop, what values do you get for the reader objects.. also I would recommend accessing the reader fields by their name not index position

Comment: in which way can i do that?

Comment: Also, don't use `*` in your query.  This will in most cases cause you to bypass indexes, or use an indexed seeks vs just using the data from an index if available (it also causes columns you aren't ever going to use to be retrieved).  And lastly, because you are retrieving by index, what happens if the columns ever get rearranged?

Comment: reader["fieldname"].ToString() or use casting where appropriate replace fieldname with actual database column name in your database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind `List<Beers>` as a `DataSource` to your `ListBox` and set the correct `DataTextField` property. Make sure that `Beer` class variables used in value or text fields are marked `Public`.

```
beerlistBox.DataSource = dbbeer.ReadBeers();
beerlistBox.DataTextField = "name"; // This should be beer's name property 
beerlistBox.DataBind();
```

Comment: DataTextField doesnt appear when i try to do your suggestion.

Comment: You are not giving us the Beer class definition, so I just guessed that the name property is called "Name". Change that to whatever beer's name property actually is.

Comment: I will add the class beer, maybe u can improve your answer

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to make your DataTextField and DataValueField properties Public.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the object itself, hence `ToString()` method of the base class is called (every objects in .NET inherit `Object Class` include your Beer Class) and that method is returning the projectname.classname. you need to use the property of your Beer Class: `name`

fix that line: `beerlistBox.Items.Add(beer.name);`

```
private void fillListbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    beerlistBox.Items.Clear();
    dbbeer.DatabaseConnect();
    List<Beer> beerList = dbbeer.ReadBeers();
    foreach (Beer beer in beerList)
    {
        beerlistBox.Items.Add(beer.name); // use the property "name"
    }
    dbbeer.DatabaseDisconnect();
}
```

alternative solution is the keep your code without any change 
and override the `ToString()` method inside beer class for example:

```
class Beer

{
    public string name;
    public string brand;
    public int dato;
    public int beertype;

    // the rest of all methods and constructors
    // ...

    // overide the base class (object class) ToString() method
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```